# How to measure data consumption by library

Tags: javascript, typescript, webcrypto-api

I've written an encryption library using webcryptoapi and typescript. I show the demo using a simple HTML Page, where there exists a button to encrypt an entered text as well as another button to decrypt the encrypted message.

For reporting and bench-marking purposes I need to show how much data would be needed run this operations on the browser like data usage approximately for mobile users, or something like that. Does any one have any idea how I could measure it on the browser and using what? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Measure the data sent over the network? The memory? You can get both from the dev tools, I guess, especially easy with the network request by just going to the network tab.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly, I'm interested in network aspect. However, AFAIK the webcrypto api runs on the browser in the js file. I mean cryptographic operations done locally, how can I measure the needed data consumption, from network standpoint. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Open the network tab and look at the requests sent and received, then.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, tried it but as I said before, now it appears that this webcrypto api is embedded to browser itself, so encryption is done locally. do you have any idea how i could measure a data consumption or estimate?

Comment: If the encryption is done locally, then there is no data consumption, as there is no network requests.